# How can i pass adapter to fragment like in intent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I am new to android and I am trying to call my `MapFragment` from adapter after on click using intent below is my code

Below is adapter code:

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
  final BusInfo info = getItem(position);
  View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.bus_only_list,null);
  TextView busname;
  busname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.busname);
  busname.setText(info.name);
  view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
       pref = context.getSharedPreferences("busInfo",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
       editor.putString("bus_name",info.name);
       editor.commit();

       Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapsFragment.class);
       intent.putExtra("name",info.name);
       context.startActivity(intent);>     

     }
  });

  return view;
}
```

I want to pass to mapfragment using intent but it redirect to `MainActivity` instead of `MapFragment`. How can I stop transferring to MainActivity?

Thank you.

Comment: you can use interface for this....

Comment: you cannot use intent to load fragments

Comment: The question is not really clear, but if you are in Fragment A and after the click you want to go to Fragment B in the same activity, your onclick should tell the MainActivity to switch to Fragment B not do anything directly involving Fragment B. MainActivity can switch the Fragment using the FragmentManager or SupportFragmentManager.

Answer (score 2):

A common pattern to passing a value to a Fragment is using `newInstance` method. In this method you can set Argument to fragment as a means to send the value.

First, create the `newInstance` method:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {
  ...

  // Creates a new fragment with bus_name
  public static YourFragment newInstance(String busName) {
    YourFragment yourFragment = new YourFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("bus_name", busName);
    yourFragment.setArguments(args);
    return yourFragment;
  }

  ...
}
```

Then you can get the value in `onCreate`:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {
  ...

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the value from arguments
    String busName = getArguments().getString("bus_name", "");  
  }

  ...
}
```

You can set the value to the Fragment from your activity with:

```
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
YourFragment yourFragment = YourFragment.newInstance("bus_name_value");
fragTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place_holder, yourFragment);
fragTransaction.commit();
```

You can use the above codes to send the value in Fragment initialization.

If you want to set the value to the already instantiated fragment, you can create a method then invoke the method to set the value:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {
  ...

  public setBusName(String busName) {
    // set the bus name to your fragment.
  }

  ...
}
```

Now, In the activity, you can invoke it with:

```
// R.id.yourFragment is the id of fragment in xml
YourFragment yourFragment = (YourFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .findFragmentById(R.id.yourFragment);
yourFragment.setBusName("bus_name_value");
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass an intent to a Fragment. Try using a Bundle instead.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putString("name", info.name);

mapFragment.setArguments(bundle)
```

In your Fragment (MapsFragment) get the Bundle like this:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

if(bundle != null){
   String infoName = bundle.getString("name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As  guys mentioned before:
1. Use callback or just casting on your context (your activity must handle changing fragments itself). 
2. To change fragments use activity's FragmentManager - intent is used to start another activity.

[Fragments Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)